# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( " in simple function

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

When I do not comment out this function:

```
function setTextField(str)
{
        if ( (str == "") ||  (str == null) ) 
          str = "Enter Task Here";
        document.getElementById.("get_subject").value = str;
}
```

I am trying to execute this from somewhere else (later in the code):

```
setTimeout('setTextField();', 1000);
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 7):

```
document.getElementById.("get_subject").value = str;
//                     ^ What's that doing there?
```

`{token}.` needs to followed by a token that is the name of a property, to be valid JS syntax (excluding some number literal syntax).

You want:

```
document.getElementById("get_subject").value = str;
```

---

Also, never, ever, *ever*, pass a string to `setTimeout`. It takes a real function!

```
setTimeout(setTextField, 1000);
```

Or if you want to execute more complex code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  setTextField(someArgument, someOtherArgument);
  //othercode
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Damn, thought I could get the anon function edit in before you :P

Comment: I swear I looked at my code 9001 times . I think I need to take a break. Thanks a lot Alex!

Comment: In modern browsers, you can actually click the syntax error in your developer console and it will show the line that caused it. At that point it should be pretty clear.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but the error it was giving me was really strange and preventing the page from loading so I could see where it was pointing to.